# How to configure Traefik to use Django Sites Framework

Tags: django, docker, traefik, cookiecutter-django, django-sites

I'm testing [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) in production using Docker-compose and Traefik with Let'sencrypt. I'm trying to configure it to work with 2 domains (mydomain1.com and mydomain2.com) using Django sites.

How to configure Traefik so it could forward traffic to necessary domain?

This is my traefik.toml

```
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]
  # http should be redirected to https
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  # https is the default
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL
[acme]
# Email address used for registration
email = "mail@mydomain1.com"
storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = false
OnHostRule = true
  # Use a HTTP-01 acme challenge rather than TLS-SNI-01 challenge
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

[file]
[backends]
  [backends.django]
    [backends.django.servers.server1]
      url = "http://django:5000"

[frontends]
  [frontends.django]
    backend = "django"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.django.headers]
      HostsProxyHeaders = ['X-CSRFToken']
    [frontends.django.routes.dr1]
      rule = "Host:mydomain1.com"
```

Now all domains working through ssl,but I can see only mydomain1.com, and mydomain2.com shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? What didn't work? By reading your question it's hard to tell.

There is an element of answer [in the issue](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/2095) you seem to have opened in cc-django repo.

First things first, I would try to take Traefik out of the equation and make this work locally by doing something as suggested. Once it works locally, it's a matter of mapping the right port/container to the right domain in Traefik.

Assuming you've configure docker-compose to run the django containers on port 5000 and 5001, I think you would need to adjust you backends and frontends section as below:

```
[backends]
  [backends.django1]
    [backends.django1.servers.server1]
      url = "http://django:5000"
  [backends.django2]
    [backends.django2.servers.server1]
      url = "http://django:5001"

[frontends]
  [frontends.django1]
    backend = "django1"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.django1.headers]
      HostsProxyHeaders = ['X-CSRFToken']
    [frontends.django1.routes.dr1]
      rule = "Host:mydomain1.com"
  [frontends.django2]
    backend = "django2"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.django2.headers]
      HostsProxyHeaders = ['X-CSRFToken']
    [frontends.django2.routes.dr1]
      rule = "Host:mydomain2.com"
```

I didn't try these, but that would be the first thing I would do. Also, it looks like we can specify [rules on frontends](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#examples) to adjust routing.